# Testing a rails controller method that is designed to change data of a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I have the following code in the controller:

```
# guest to user sign up view. Method that prepares a guest to become a user by emptying it's generic
#e-mail address.
def guest_signup
  if !current_user.guest
    redirect_to root_url
  end
  @user = current_user
  @user.email = ""
end
```

This controller just makes sure that the outcome (a form) doesn't have a generic e-mail address in an input field that the user gets assigned when he is using the application as guest.

I am trying to write an rspec test for it and I have no idea how to properly do it... I know this may sound like development-driven testing rather than the opposite but I need an idea. 
Currently I have this that doesn't work:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  describe "Guest Signup" do
    it "should prepare guest with random e-mail user for signup form, emptying the e-mail" do
      current_user = User.create(:email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@example.com", :password => "#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99999999)}", :guest => true)
      get :guest_signup, :user => @user.id
      expect(@user.email).to eq ('')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How is `@user` assigned here? Presumably after the `guest_signup` method is called. Since `@user` is referenced in the call to `guest_signup`, you have an order of operations problem here.

Maybe you should be calling:

```
get :guest_signup, :user => current_user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
describe UsersController do
  describe 'Guest Signup' do

    let(:user) { mock.as_null_object }
    before(:each) { controller.stub(:current_user) { user } }

    context 'when guest does not exist' do

      before(:each) { user.stub(:guest) { false } }

      it 'redirects to root path' do
        get :guest_signup
        response.should redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

    context 'when guest exists' do

      before(:each) { user.stub(:guest) { true } }

      it 'should prepare guest with random e-mail user for signup form, emptying the e-mail' do
        get :guest_signup
        assigns(@user).should == user
        assigns(@email).should be_empty
      end
    end
  end
end
```